# Why is the region in Drupal blank?

Tags: drupal-7, block, regions

I my .info file I have this:

```
regions[footermenu] = Footer Menu
```

The region--footer.tp.php has this:

```
<?php
    print render($page['footermenu']);
?>
```

I've placed a menu block in the "Footer Menu" (it shows up under structure->blocks). However, it's blank. If I place the block in region I know works the menu content is seen fine. Any idea why the region wouldn't see the block?

Answer (score 0):

1. It may just be a typo in your question, but check that the template's file name ends with '.tpl.php'.
2. The code that triggers the rendering of your region, namely `<?php print render ($page['footermenu']); ?>`, goes in 'page.tpl.php', which in turn will render 'region.tpl.php' (or 'region--footermenu.tpl.php' in your specific case).
3. You will have to clear the theme's cache when you add a new template file. That can be done simply by visiting your theme's settings page.